# Having trouble using the BinaryDerive.hs Script, for generating Binary instances

Tags: haskell, binary

I'm trying to run the BinaryDerive.hs script as per the instructions in the Data.Binary doc, which states:

> To derive the instance for a type,
> load this script into GHCi, and bring
> your type into scope. Your type can
> then have its Binary instances derived
> as follows:
>
> $ ghci -fglasgow-exts BinaryDerive.hs
>
> *BinaryDerive> :l Example.hs
> *Main> deriveM (undefined :: Drinks)

However when I try to follow those instructions I get:

> c:\Scripts\Haskell>$ ghci -fglasgow-exts BinaryDerive.hs
>
> *BinaryDerive> :l TemperatureRecord.hs
> [1 of 1] Compiling TemperatureRecord (TemperatureRecord.hs, interpreted )
>
> Ok, modules loaded:TemperatureRecord.
>
> *TemperatureRecord> deriveM (undefined :: TemperatureRecord)
>
> (interactive):1:0: Not in scope: 'deriveM'

I am assuming that there is an additional step that was not specified that a beginner, like myself would not be aware of. It seems the root of the problem is that loading the TemperatureRecord takes BinaryDerive out of scope. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers. I tried both of them and neither worked, however, the answers I saw did lead me too a solution.

```
$ ghci -fglasgow-exts -XDeriveDataTypeable
Prelude> :l Binaryderive TemperatureRecord
Prelude> :m Binaryderive TemperatureRecord
Prelude BinaryDerive TemperatureRecord>deriveM (undefined :: TemperatureRecord)
```

The above worked for me. However, I am not using that solution in practice. I am working on getting a more automatic solution to work. Anyway thanks for helping me get something that works.

Comment: You're actually looking for a `derive` tool.  Two exist to my knowledge.  [Derive](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/derive/) and [DriFT](http://repetae.net/computer/haskell/DrIFT/).  Using these tools you can [just add a pseudo-comment](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/derive/derive.htm) to the `deriving` clause in your data declaration then run `derive` on the .hs file to generate the requested instances.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$ ghci -fglasgow-exts

Prelude> :l BinaryDerive TemperatureRecord
```

the .hs's are not necessary

Then you can access TemperatureRecord in a similar manner to this example (JSON Doc type taken from [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/writing-a-library-working-with-json-data.html#id600358), with some added Data and Typeable derives)

```
$ ghci -fglasgow-exts -XDeriveDataTypeable
Prelude> :l Binaryderive JSON
[1 of 2] Compiling JSON             ( JSON.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 2] Compiling BinaryDerive     ( Binaryderive.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: BinaryDerive, JSON.
*BinaryDerive> deriveM (undefined::JSON.Doc)
instance Binary JSON.Doc where
  put Empty = putWord8 0
  put (Char a) = putWord8 1 >> put a
  put (Text a) = putWord8 2 >> put a
  put Line = putWord8 3
  put (Concat a b) = putWord8 4 >> put a >> put b
  put (Union a b) = putWord8 5 >> put a >> put b
  get = do
    tag_ <- getWord8
    case tag_ of
      0 -> return Empty
      1 -> get >>= \a -> return (Char a)
      2 -> get >>= \a -> return (Text a)
      3 -> return Line
      4 -> get >>= \a -> get >>= \b -> return (Concat a b)
      5 -> get >>= \a -> get >>= \b -> return (Union a b)
      _ -> fail "no parse"
```

Answer (score 1):

My understanding of ghci's loading/namespacing mechanisms is full of holes, but since nobody else has answered, here are some guessses:

1. Try `:m + BinaryDerive` after `:l Example.hs`
2. Add `import BinaryDerive` at the top of Example.hs
3. Don't add `module TemperatureRecord where` at the top of Example.hs